# How to erase non-alpha chars and lowercase the alpha chars in a single pass of a string?

Tags: c++, string, stl-algorithm

Given a string:

```
std::string str{"This i_s A stRIng"};
```

Is it possible to transform it to lowercase and remove all non-alpha characters in a single pass?

Expected result:

```
this is a string
```

I know you can use `std::transform(..., ::tolower)` and `string.erase(remove_if())` combination to make two passes, or it can be done manually by iterating each character, but is there a way to do something that would combine the `std::transform` and `erase` calls without having to run through the string multiple times?

Comment: Any chance you're using C++20?  Ranges are excellent at combining algorithms in one pass.

Comment: You're asking a lot just to save one line of code.  If you're worried about the extra time it takes to do two passes, don't until your benchmarking shows it to be a significant bottleneck.

Comment: It's certainly simple to do if iterating manually...

Comment: @MarkRansom I figured there was a simple way to do so that I wasn't aware of. If there are no simple (copy-free) alternatives, then I'll do just that.

Comment: I think two separate "passes" is not inefficient, since the tolower will work in-place and not recopy the string.  Only the removal pass will shift the characters down.  And `remove_if` will be faster because it will only shift everything once, while the simple loop would delete one at a time, recopying everything to the right of the deleted char multiple times.  You would need to inject the transform into the "smart" `remove_if` logic.  I think the technology of the Range library is capable of generating code that efficient, but don't know the specific calls to achieve that.

Comment: You want the code to be **_simple (copy-free)_** and you also want it in one line. Using short code won't make it perform faster. And any of the suggested answers are surely not "simple" despite being short.

Comment: @brc-dd while I did state "separate lines" in my original post, I by no means meant for it to imply the solution had to be a one-liner. I'm looking for a single-pass solution with already existing algorithms, if it exists.

Answer (score 3):

C++20 ranges allow algorithms to be combined, in a one-pass fashion.

```
std::string str{"This i_s A stRIng"};
std::string out;

auto is_alpha_or_space = [](unsigned char c){ return isalpha(c) || isspace(c); };
auto safe_tolower = [](unsigned char c){ return tolower(c); };

std::ranges::copy( str
    | std::views::filter(is_alpha_or_space)
    | std::views::transform(safe_tolower)
    , std::back_inserter(out));
```

[See it on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/xE87YEsEc)

Comment: Passing negative characters to `isalpha`, `tolower`, etc, is UB. You need to cast to `unsigned char`, which makes this less pretty. :/

Answer (score 2):

First let me notice that you seem to want to filter alphabetic characters *or* spaces, that is, characters `l` for which `std::isalpha(l) || std::isspace(l)` returns true.

Assuming this, you can achieve what you want using [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

```
str = std::accumulate(str.begin(), str.end(), std::string{},
    [](const std::string& s, const auto& l) {
        if (std::isalpha(l, std::locale()) || std::isspace(l, std::locale()))
             return s + std::tolower(l, std::locale());
        else
             return s;
    });
```

See it [Live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ed307a7b197847c).

Comment: Functionally it works but this can be a performance killer. `accumulate` returns by copy. I am not sure if compiler can see through returning a copy of argument and working in-place on the target, especially on `std::string` which has a complicated c'tor. I would even say calling it a single pass is debatable, because returning from lambda will make multiple passes over the already processed characters during copy.

Comment: `isalpha` and similar functions have to be given `unsigned char`s, otherwise you risk UB.

Comment: @luk32 Agree on the performance caviat, although one should obviously benchmark it. However, notice that from c++20 accumulate applies ```std::move```.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks for the comment, see updated code.

Comment: Still has the same problem I think? Changing the parameter to `unsigned char l` to force the conversion would work.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I suppose you are right. I guess it is safer, and more generic, to use the functions from std::locale, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I know you can ... do it manually by iterating each character ...

That is exactly would you would have to do, eg:

```cpp
std::string str{"This i_s A stRIng"};

std::string::size_type pos = 0;
while (pos < str.size())
{
    unsigned char ch = str[pos];
    if (!::isalpha(ch))
    {
        if (!::isspace(ch))
        {
            str.erase(pos, 1);
            continue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        str[pos] = (char) ::tolower(ch);
    }
    ++pos;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
std::string str{"This i_s A stRIng"};

auto iter = str.begin();
while (iter != str.end())
{
    unsigned char ch = *iter;
    if (!::isalpha(ch))
    {
        if (!::isspace(ch))
        {
            iter = str.erase(iter);
            continue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        *iter = (char) ::tolower(ch);
    }
    ++iter;
}
```

> but is there a way to do something that would combine the std::transform and erase calls without having to run through the string multiple times?

You can use the standard `std::accumulate()` algorithm, as shown in [francesco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68215787/65863).  Although, that will not manipulate the `std::string` in-place, as the code above does.  It will create a new `std::string` instead (and will do so on each iteration, for that matter).

Otherwise, you could use C++20 ranges, ie by combining [`std::views::filter()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view) with [`std::views::transform()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view), eg (I'm not familiar with the `<ranges>` library, so this syntax might need tweaking):

```cpp
#include <ranges>

auto alphaOrSpace = [](unsigned char ch){ return ::isalpha(ch) || ::isspace(ch); }
auto lowercase = [](unsigned char ch){ return ::tolower(ch); };

std::string str{"This i_s A stRIng"};

str = str | std::views::filter(alphaOrSpace) | std::views::transform(lowercase);
```

But, this would actually be a multi-pass solution, just coded into a single operation.

Comment: Not an answer.  OP stated, "I know you can ... do it manually by iterating each character, **but** is there a way ..."

Comment: re your edit:  You should just delete the first part of the answer.  BTW, the ranges example is still making two passes, just writing it on one line.